# new element created that calling to jquery method after ready document doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//  When change the value in select it will send id to controller in order to return the price of service.
$(".select-service").change(function(){
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post("/services/get_price_of", {
        message: this.value
    },
    function(data){
        $("#" + element_id).parent().find(".price-input").val(data);

    })
});

});
```

The page is loaded with one select but I can add more select dynamically. The problem is that for all select added  dynamically, the event early does not work.
Can someone help me?

Regards.

P.D: sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery `on`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("select").on("change", ".select-service", function(event){
         var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("/services/get_price_of", {
            message: this.value
        },
        function(data){
            $("#" + element_id).parent().find(".price-input").val(data);

        })
    });
});
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and its `selector` parameter. For example, to capture all clicks on `p` elements in `#container` (even `p` elements added after the event listener was attached), you could use this code:

```
$("#container").on('click', 'p', function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Additionally, although not related to your problem, a more elegant approach to using the target of the event inside a callback is this:

```
var self = $(this);
someFunction(function() {
    self.css('color', 'red');
});
```