# Jquery not working for the elements created after document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, i am adding a whole set of new elements on clicking a "+"/plus button.

But the problem is, since am appending the new elements only during clicking, the elements are not responding to the jquery events.

Bellow is an event in my scenarios:

```
$("#form input[type='text']").blur(validateField);
```

This event is working for all the input element EXCEPT for the once i appended dymanically on clicking "+"/plus button.

How can i resolve it? can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [new element created that calling to jquery method after ready document doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543239/new-element-created-that-calling-to-jquery-method-after-ready-document-doesnt-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with delegating the event to the static parent:

```
$("#form").on('blur', 'input[type="text"]', validateField);
```

Answer (score 5):

Delegate event:

```
$(document.body).on('focusout',"#form input[type='text']",validateField);
```

As onblur event doesn't bubble by default, use onfocusout event instead.

EDIT: just checked, jquery now add delegation support for onblur event by mapping onblur event.

> The blur event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. Therefore,
>   scripts that rely on event delegation with the blur event will not
>   work consistently across browsers. As of version 1.4.2, however,
>   jQuery works around this limitation by mapping blur to the focusout
>   event in its event delegation methods, .live() and .delegate().

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `on()`

```
$("#form input[type='text']").on("blur",validateField);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.on()` or `.live()` or `.delegate()` method for these newly created elements. It will work.

Comment: [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) deprecated jquery 1.7 and removed after jquery 1.9

Comment: I know that, but what if OP is using those versions? He has not mentioned it. Or it is always better to use `delegate` or `on` methods.

Comment: you should add details... as he also not mentioned that he is using outdated jQuery :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will take care of it next time onwards.